# How make planning description wizard with a collada?

Tags: robotic-arm, collada, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a collada file for my robot and no a urdf.
I want use the planning_description_wizard to use arm navigation after.
I know, I can't change my collada in a urdf but it's possible to use the collada for it ?

I want use this tutorial:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/tools/Planning%20Description%20Configuration%20Wizard
But this function no works with collada file:
$ roslaunch planning_environment planning_description_configuration_wizard.launch urdf_package:= urdf_path:=

thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36424/how-make-planning-description-wizard-with-a-collada-?/) by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to load the collada file directly into the wizard, as all it does is call the urdf parser with the file and the urdf parser supports collada.  Specify the package location and path like you would for a urdf and post output if it fails to load.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2012-08-07**:
It's true, works but no works with lot of computer and with different error, it's very strange.
Currently works with a new computer. Thanks for your answer